# Como criar variáveis para status de um pedido?

Tags: c#

De que forma posso criar variáveis para servir como possíveis status de um pedido?
Depois de o pedido já feito, quero criar opções para que quando o atendente digite, o status do pedido seja alterado. As opções podem ser:
1-Em trânsito
2-Cancelado
3-Entregue

```
string Cliente = ""; //Cria a variável Cliente em branco
Console.Write("Cliente: "); //Escreve "Cliente" na tela para o usuário.
Cliente = Console.ReadLine(); //Insere na memória o que foi digitado pelo usuário.

--

List<string> Fila;
Fila = new List<string>(); //Fila criada com 10 elementos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize um enum:

```
public enum StatusPedido 
{
   EmTransito = 1,
   Cancelado = 2,
   Entregue = 3
}
```

Então na sua classe `Pedido`:

```
public class Pedido 
{
    ...
    public StatusPedido Status { get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Coloque um pouco do seu código e eu edito para se adaptar a ele. Por exemplo, como vai receber o status do pedido, qual tecnologia está usando (ASP.NET, Windows Forms. WPF). Enums são ótimos candidatos para representar status, sem usar números mágicos ou strings.

Comment: string Pedido = (("Cliente:") + Cliente + (Environment.NewLine + "Produto:") + Produto + (Environment.NewLine + "Tamanho:") + Tamanho + (Environment.NewLine + "Quantidade") + Quantidade);
            //Adiciona o pedido a memória

Comment: string resp = Console.ReadLine(); //Lê a resposta do usuário para a confirmação do pedido

            if (resp == "S") //se a resposta for sim, exibe mensagem de sucesso e pergunta se deseja adicionar outro pedido
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pedido:" + Pedido);
                Fila.Add(Pedido);
                Console.Write("Pedido Registrado! Deseja adicionar outro pedido? (S/N)");

Comment: Você está usando uma aplicação console então. Edite sua pergunta e adicione lá o código, o máximo que achar relevante. Por que ao invés de guardar o pedido com string na lista, não usa um classe Pedido. Ai pode editar o Status do pedido como eu te mostrei na resposta.